# DRF Create a custom relational data or smth similar?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have three models, one called Events and one called Tasks. Each one has a field called deadline.
**Goal**: I need to create a section in my Custom User model called Todis and a section called Overdose where I filter the Events and tasks that has deadline less than now and put them in the todos and I need to filter the other Tasks and Events object to put them in the overdoes.

```
from Myapp import Events
from MyOtherApp import Tasks
User(models.Model):
  field1 = models...
  field2 = models...
  def smthing(self,args,kwargs);
    # here create new field 
    # Events and Tasks are other models
    for event in Events.objects.all():
       if event.deadline < now():
          self.Ovedows.append(event)
    for tasks in Tasks.objects.all():
       if tasks.deadline < now():
          self.Ovedows.append(tasks)
```

I know how to filter and all this stuff but I need an idea to get that data and set them inside the user module without creating a new data field together them, just like using the relational data

Comment: kindly share some code, look at those articles stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question to add relevant code (and fix your typos)

Comment: ok here I add it @Jimmar      .

Answer (score 1):

I think you need do something like this

```py
from datetime import datetime

class User(models.Model):
  #....
  def overdue_tasks(self):
    now = datetime.now()
    return Tasks.objects.filter(deadline__lt=now)
  def overdue_events(self):
    now = datetime.now()
    return Events.objects.filter(deadline__lt=now)
```

`deadline__lt` means deadline less than which is equivalent to `deadline < now`

Since you need them from 2 different models, you'll need to merge them in the serializer or somewhere in the front end

Note that this currently fetches ALL the events for ALL the users, you didn't share your models properly (didn't share the Tasks and Events models) so I don't know how you are linking them to the User model, you should have a foreign key in them pointing to the user model.

assuming your Tasks model looks like this

```py
class Tasks(models.Model):
  deadline = ...
  user = models. ForeignKey(User)
```

the query will instead be

```py
self.tasks_set.filter(deadline__lt=now)
# and
self.events_set.filter(deadline__lt=now)
```